# Z-Index/Overflow issue?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Please reference the previous question linked here: [IE7 Subnav, two positioning issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533096/ie7-subnav-two-positioning-issues)

The second comment shows a solution to my original problem, which I have since implemented.

Now, I am having an issue with z-index/overflow not only on IE7 but every browser.

The website in question: http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/

When hovering over home or about, you'll find a subnav that falls behind the body content.  I have tried seemingly, every z-index and/or overflow combination I can think of to no avail.

This should be very easy but I'm just not seeing the solution.

**Edit:**
Added `position:absolute and z-index:10` to `.main-nav`.  This fixed the problem in all but IE7.  Now, in IE7 tthe sub-navs fall behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give z-index to the parent element. In this case the class "main-nav". Just add position:absolute and z-index:10.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: This certainly fixes the problem in everything but IE7.  In which case, the nav still falls behind the text below it, which interferes with hovering into the subnavs.

Comment: Michael, I am looking your site and I notive that you matbe solved the menu problem. The unique problem is that the full-banner is without a position.